ERROR Uncaught TypeError: $.validator.unobtrusive is undefined. EN .NET CORE 8
cree un archivo bundles para jqueryvalidation. Me da el siguiente error
Uncaught TypeError: $.validator.unobtrusive is undefined.
Las lineas donde me da el error es en el siguiente codigo, estoy trabajando con .net core 8 en una arquitectura MVC

$.validator.unobtrusive is undefined en
var $pageContent = $('');

    $pageContent.load(url, function () {
        var $form = $('#ABMForm');
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
        $form.submit(function (e) {
            var $form = $(this);
            if ($form.valid()) {
                Q.serviceCall({
                    service: $form.attr('action'),
                    request: $form.serialize(),
                    onSuccess: function (response) {
                        if (typeof response.status != 'undefined') {
                            if (response.status) {
                                Q.notifySuccess(response.message);
                                if (options.codigoName != null) {
                                    if (!Q.isEmptyOrNull(response.data.Codigo)) {
                                        $form.find('#' + options.codigoName).val(response.data.Codigo);
                                    }
                                }
                                if (options.tableReload == null) {
                                    table.ajax.reload();
                                } else {
                                    if (options.tableReload) {
                                        table.ajax.reload();
                                    }
                                }
                                if (options.autoClosed == null) {
                                    dialog.dialog('destroy');
                                } else {
                                    if (options.autoClosed) {
                                        dialog.dialog('destroy');
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                Q.notifyError(response.message)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Q.notifyError(Q.Message.validateform)
                return false;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });

El orden de carga de los scripts es el siguiente
<script src="~/bundles/inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/bundles/datatables.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/bundles/jqueryval.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/bundles/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

Como lo soluciono?.
